# Как сделать анимацию загрузки по кругу?

Tags: javascript, html, css3, canvas, css-animation

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача заключаеться в том, чтоб когда пользователь доскролил до данного блока то border, он как загрузка закрашиваеться, а цифры от нуля перебираються до нужного значения

Comment: не смог найти адекватное решение, если знаешь ссылку пришли

Comment: Вот статья с использованием плагина https://smartlanding.biz/animaciya-chisel.html

Comment: а как сделать круг?

Comment: В поисковик "border progress bar js". А потом вставляешь его туда же, где выполняется код с цифрами.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В скрипт можно не смотреть, все существующие настройки указаны в атрибуте data-options

```js
class Loop {
  constructor() {
    this.frameId = null
    this.updatable = {}
    this.length = 0
    
    this.update = this.update.bind(this)
  }
  
  update(t) {
    for (const member in this.updatable) this.updatable[member](t)
    if (this.length > 0) this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
  }
  
  add(name, fn) {
    this.updatable[name] = fn

    if (this.length === 0) {
      this.length++
      this.run()
      return
    }

    this.length++
  }
  
  remove(name) {
    if (!this.updatable[name]) return

    delete this.updatable[name]
    this.length = Math.max(0, this.length - 1)
    if (this.length === 0) this.stop()
  }
  
  run() {
    this.stop()
    this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
  }
  
  stop() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId)
  }
}

class OptionsParser {
  constructor(str, defaultOptions) {
    this.defaultOptions = defaultOptions
    this.options = {}
    
    this.parseOptions(str)
    this.applyOptions()
  }
  
  parseOptions(str) {
    str
      .split(',')
      .map(option => option.trim())
      .filter(option => !!option)
      .forEach(option => {
      
      const parts = option
        .split('=')
        .map(option => option.trim())
        .filter(option => !!option)
      
      if(parts[1] === 'false') {
        this.options[parts[0]] = false
      }

      else if(parts[1] === 'true') {
        this.options[parts[0]] = true
      }

      else if(isNaN(parts[1])) {
        this.options[parts[0]] = parts[1] ? parts[1] : true
      }
  
      else if(!isNaN(parts[1])){
        this.options[parts[0]] = +parts[1]
      }
    })

  }
  
  applyOptions() {
    for(const member in this.defaultOptions) {
      this.options[member] = this.options[member] || this.defaultOptions[member]
    }
  }
}

class Canvas {
  constructor(node) {
    if(!node) return;

    this.node = node
    this.context = this.node.getContext('2d')

    this.width = 0
    this.height = 0

    this.resize()
    addEventListener('resize', this.resize.bind(this))
  }

  resize() {
    this.node.width = this.width = this.node.offsetWidth
    this.node.height = this.height = this.node.offsetHeight
  }
}


class Progress extends OptionsParser {
  constructor(container) {
    super(
      container.getAttribute('data-options'),
      { from: 0, to: 100, step: 1, delay: 0.01, strokeColor: 'black', strokeWidth: 1 }
    )
    
    this.container = container
    if(!this.container) return;

    this.bind()
    
    this.out = this.container.querySelector('[data-progress-out]')
    this.canvas = new Canvas(this.container.querySelector('[data-progress-canvas]'))
     
    this.loop = new Loop()
    
    this.interval = null
    this.rid = null
    this.counter = 0
    this.t = 0
    this.circlePx = 0
    this.circlePy = 0
    
    this.id = Date.now()
    
    if(this.canvas.node) {
      this.resize()
      addEventListener('resize', this.resize.bind(this))
    }
    
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(this.run, { threshold: 0 })
    this.observer.observe(this.container)
  }

  bind() {
    this.run = this.run.bind(this)
  }
  
  startDrawing() {
    if(!this.canvas.node) return;
     
    const st = Date.now()
    const dur = this.options.delay * (this.options.to - this.options.from) / this.options.step

    this.loop.add(this.id, () => {
      this.t = (Date.now() - st) / (dur * 1000)
      
      this.drawCircle(this.t)

      if(this.t >= 1) this.loop.remove(this.id)
    })
  }

  drawCircle(t) {
    this.canvas.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height)
    this.canvas.context.beginPath()
    this.canvas.context.arc(this.circlePx, this.circlePy, this.circlePx - this.options.strokeWidth, 0, Math.PI * 2 * t)
    this.canvas.context.strokeStyle = this.options.strokeColor
    this.canvas.context.lineWidth = this.options.strokeWidth
    this.canvas.context.stroke()
  }
  
  updateCounter() {
    if(!this.out) return;

    const intervalCallback = () => {
      this.counter += this.options.step
      this.out.innerText = this.options.from + this.counter

      if (this.options.from + this.counter > this.options.to) {
        this.out.innerText = this.options.to
        clearInterval(this.interval)
      }
    }
    
    this.interval = setInterval(intervalCallback, this.options.delay * 1000)
    intervalCallback()
  }

  resize() {
    this.circlePx = this.container.offsetWidth / 2
    this.circlePy = this.container.offsetHeight / 2
  
    this.drawCircle(this.t)
  }
  
  run(entries) {
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting) {
      this.observer.unobserve(this.container)
      
      this.updateCounter()
      this.startDrawing()
    }
  }
}



document.querySelectorAll('[data-progress]').forEach(progress => new Progress(progress))
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 260vh;
}

[data-progress] {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
}

[data-progress-out] {
  font-size: 10vmin;
}

[data-progress-canvas] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

[data-progress]:nth-child(1) {
  top: 30vh;
}

[data-progress]:nth-child(2) {
  top: 60vh;
}

[data-progress]:nth-child(3) {
  top: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<div data-progress data-options="from = 0, to = 100, step = 1, delay = 0.05, strokeColor = tomato, strokeWidth = 2">
  <canvas data-progress-canvas></canvas>
  <div data-progress-out></div>
</div>
<div data-progress data-options="from = 0, to = 1000, step = 10, delay = 0.01, strokeColor = lightblue, strokeWidth = 6">
  <canvas data-progress-canvas></canvas>
  <div data-progress-out></div>
</div>
<div data-progress data-options="from = 50, to = 190, step = 3, delay = 0.1, strokeColor = lightgreen, strokeWidth = 12">
  <canvas data-progress-canvas></canvas>
  <div data-progress-out></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Где-то ошибка, круг "заканчивается" при 80%